# maximum number of elements which can be added to an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, hashset

Question :-

You're given a string S of N characters. It's known that the string consists of lowercase latin letters. The string is generated randomly. That means that every symbol is chosen randomly and independently from others from the set {'a', 'b', ..., 'z'}. All the letters has equal probability to appear.

You're given Q queries on this string. Each query is of the form P C, where P is an integer between 1 and N (both inclusive) and C is a character from the set {'a', 'b', ..., 'z'}. Both P and C were chosen at random and independently from other queries.

When you have a query of the form P C you have to change the Pth symbol of S to C. After every change we ask you to output the number of distinct nonempty sub-strings of S.

Input Format 
The first line of input consists of two single space separated integers N and Q - the length of the string S and the number of queries respectively.

The second line contains the string S itself.

The following Q lines describe the queries in the form P C, where P and C are also separated with a single space.

Constraints

4 ≤ N ≤ 75000 
4 ≤ Q ≤ 75000

Output Format 
Output Q lines. Output the number of distinct substrings of S after the ith query on the ith line of the output.

Sample Input

```
4 4 
aaab
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
```

Sample Output :-

```
7
7
9
10
```

Explanation :-

after replacing the character at 1st index with a, we still have the original string aaab. The total non empty substrings of aaab are

a b aa ab aaa aab aaab
hence 7.

after replacing the character at 2nd index with b, we have the string abab. The total non empty substrings of abab are

a b ab ba aba bab abab
hence 7.

after replacing the character at 3rd index with c, we have the string abcb. The total non empty substrings of abcb are

a b c ab bc cb abc bcb abcb
hence 9.

after replacing the character at 4th index with d, we have the string abcd. The total non empty substrings of abcd are

a b c d ab bc cd abc bcd abcd
hence 10.

my code :-

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution 
{
 public static long count(String string)
 {
    String sub;
    int i,c,length;
    ArrayList<String>al=new ArrayList<String>();
    length = string.length();

    for(c=0;c<length;c++)
    {
        for(i=1;i<=length-c;i++)
        {
            sub = string.substring(c,c+i);
            al.add(sub);
        }
    }

    HashSet hs = new HashSet();
    hs.addAll(al);
    al.clear();
    al.addAll(hs);

    return al.size();
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int q = sc.nextInt();

    String s = sc.next();
    StringBuilder m = new StringBuilder(s);
    while((q--)>0)
    {
        int p = sc.nextInt() - 1;
        char c = sc.next().toCharArray()[0];
        m.setCharAt(p,c);
        String z = m.toString();
        long x = count(z);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
 }
}
```

when input is very large like and if the answer is more than the 2147483647 ( maximum int value ) for example say 2812324482 .... i get wrong output

As we all know size() method returns int so it's maximum capacity is 2147483647 , but my answer is expected to be more than that which couldn't be accomodated

Can anyone give me an idea to store more value or any other alternative manual or predefined method which returns the size of arraylist whose maximum capacity is more than 2147483647?

Comment: You couldn't store that many object instances in memory anyway. Perhaps you should consider a different approach.

Comment: May be increasing the size of main memory help ?

Comment: Yeah...if you're trying to solve a problem like this by actually storing all the possibilities, you've lost before you've started.

Comment: it mentioned 'distinct' substrings so i had to use hashset else i would have used long count =0; and i would have incremented it @LouisWasserman

Comment: May I ask why you copy the `HashSet`’s contents to the `ArrayList` instead of just query the `size()` of the `HashSet`?

Comment: @coder101: I'm saying the intended solution to the problem doesn't entail actually constructing all the distinct substrings, just calculating the correct number of them without actually listing them out.

Comment: yes i can return the size of hashset by using size() , but even it returns int so it might not make any difference @Holger

Comment: @LouisWasserman what if i use more than one arraylist's and if size of an arraylist is exceeded then if i add it to another arraylist and proceed so on?

Comment: @coder101: actually, you don't need an `ArrayList` at all, just a `HashSet`, if you want to count the number of distinct substrings. And of course, it makes a difference whether you need storage for each *distinct* string or for each permutation. That may still not be the best solution but it illustrates how little you take care about efficiency...

Comment: @Holger yes i tried to do that too bro , but it didnt work , the reason for using arraylist then adding it to hashset is that it took lesser time to execute when given large input ..... when i added each element to hashset it took 3.27 seconds , but when used arraylist it took 2.62 seconds

Comment: @coder101 Frankly _any_ solution which requires instantiating more than Integer.MAX_VALUE objects is a nonstarter, regardless of how you try to arrange it so they're not all in one ArrayList.

Comment: coder101: *how* should adding elements to an `ArrayList`, followed by adding the same elements to a `HashSet` be faster than adding these elements to a `HashSet` only? Not that it matters for a non-working solution...

Comment: @Holger i don't know the exact reason but when i executed it , it took more time.... when i added each element to hashset it took 3.27 seconds , but when used arraylist it took 2.62 seconds

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of item contained by an `ArrayList` is depends on implementation. Since `List<Integer>` is different from `List<Person>`, so the maximum number of items in these two `List` should be different.

Comment: Even if you have infinite memory (e.g. 200 GBs of ram), both of them have the same boundary: the array used in `ArrayList` for the implementation, which size cannot exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (in fact, the maximum size of an array is less than this value).